# In MongoDB, is bulkWrite slower than insert for a single document?

Tags: mongodb

Only for inserting a single document. The code which inserts the document may be called multiple times in succession.

BulkWrite used as follows (java driver):

```java
MongoTemplate template;
RandomDocument doc;
template.bulkOps(BulkMode.UNORDERED, "myCollection").insert(doc).execute();
```

Comment: At least some mongo drivers like for java and c# call `BulkWrite` for all C_UD operations internally. So effectively there is no difference between insertOne and BulkWrite (at least from performance POV). I assume same behavior presents in other languages too

Comment: I was using the `spring-data-mongodb` driver, and this *seems* to hold: insertOne results in a MixedBulkWriteOperation. Thanks!